# Contextual Advertising API like Gmail Ads

Tags: advertising, api

Which advertising network has an API I can use to show my users targeted ads based on certain dictionary words present in their user-generated content, similar to Gmail's targeted ads?

**Edit:** The user-generated content is not public and is therefore not indexed by Google, so AdSense is not an option.

Comment: Um, Adsense ...

Comment: @John, the content is not public and is therefore not indexed by Google. And if it's not indexed, it can't be contextualised by AdSense.

Comment: If it's not public you'd need to work out a way for someone to index it to be able to determine what Ad's they want to show with your content. A keyword isn't enough data for someone to decide if your page is exactly what they want to advertise on or not.

Comment: ...which is why I'm looking for an advertising API to which I can feed an anonymised set of words based on the user's private content.

Comment: I don't know of any ad network that will let you do that - mostly because people would game the system passing in fake keywords once they figure out what pays the best. There are ad servers you can use to do that - but then you would need to sell the ads yourself.

Comment: @James, good point about people gaming the system. I guess AdSense is the way to go. Are there any similar alternatives to AdSense, though?

Comment: You could check out AdRoll - they are doing lots of retargeting lately which should help bump your revenue. It also doesn't rely on contextual ads as much as adsense. The other good option would be to find one in your vertical market - what is the site's focus?

Comment: @James, it's the [Simplest. To Do List. Ever.](http://CoolToDoList.com/) and it's still in beta. I can't really charge for this service, so I'm looking at showing contextual ads based on users' lists like GMail does for email without lists being public.

Comment: There are some really interesting things you could do with a To Do List - drop me a line if you want to chat about it more. javery at adzerk.com

Comment: Instead of an API, have you considered Javascript based ad-injection? A lot of services offer this where you only need to put their Javascript on your page.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Semantic Engine's Contextual Advertising API.

> Contextual Advertising API features include:
>
> - analyzing the content of a page on-the-fly and matching it to a relevant advertising category;
> - extraction of key concepts from a page.

Free trial available.

- http://www.semanticengines.com/contextualadapi.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at adzerk, it serves the ads as well as gives you all the back end dashborad / monitoring - `www.adzerk.com`.